# Printer compatibility

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I have a doubt. Is any printer bluetooth device compatible with Android SDK? In particular, I would like to develop an Android app to print by Citizen PD24 mobile printer with bluetooth connection. PD24 datasheet doesn't specify if it is compatible with android devices, but I am not sure if I can use it with BluetoothSocket API.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Citizen printer sdks for Android (or iOS), you'll have to get some of their newer devices. Here are their [official sdks](http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/english/support/download/printer/sdk/index.html). And here are three Android demo programs created using those sdks:
[mdemo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citizen.app.mdemo), [pdemo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citizen.app.pdemo), and [pnumticket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citizen.app.pnumticket).

Unfortunately, the PD24 is an older model and it's only being supported by the manufacturer on the (old) Windows CE mobile platform (I suppose you could try to reverse-engineer that Windows CE sdk code to try to make it work for Android, but that's just not something I'd be qualified to talk about).